# overloading a Perl object to redirect hash access to custom routine

Tags: perl, overloading

A while ago, I wrote a routine that parses a given string and returns a record in the form of a hash `(field => value, field2 => value2)`. Great, except requirements have changed and I now need to return more data and offer getter methods to get at this data. So, I adjusted the routine to return a `Record` object which stores this same hash in a `data` attribute.

However, this will break legacy code that expects a hash so that it can get at the data using `$record->{field}`. With the new `Record` object, the path to this data is now `$record->{data}->{field}` or `$record->getByShortName('field')`.

My idea was to overload the object's FETCH method and return the corresponding field. However, this does not seem to work. It looks like FETCH is never called.

I'm looking for three pieces of advice:

1. How can I overload my object correctly so that hash access attempts are redirected to a custom method of the object?
2. Is this an advisable way of working or will there be a massive speed penalty?
3. Are there better methods to keep backward compatibility in my case?

Here's an MVE:

**Record.pm**

```perl
package Record;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use overload fallback => 1, '%{}' => \&access_hash;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    my %fields = (answer =>  42, question => 21);
    $args{fields} = \%fields;
    return bless { %args }, $class;
}

sub access_hash {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self;  # cannot return $self->{fields} because that would recurse ad infinitum
}

sub FETCH {
    print(Dumper(@_));  # does not return anything, is this method not being called
}
```

**test.pl**

```perl
use Record;

my $inst = Record->new();

print($inst->{answer}."\n");
print($inst->{question}."\n");
```

Comment: `FETCH` is a method of tied variables, which is a separate mechanism from overloaded packages.

Answer (score 6):

`Record` is a blessed hash reference, so if you overload the `%{}` operator, you will have trouble accessing the fields of the underlying hash.

The `overload` authors thought about this, and provided the `overloading` pragma as a way to disable overloading for this and some other use cases.

```
use overload '%{}' => \&access_hash;
...
sub access_hash {
    no overloading '%{}';
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{fields};
}
```

---

Prior to Perl 5.10, the workaround was to disable overloading by temporarily reblessing your object to something that wouldn't activate your overloaded operators.

```
sub access_hash {
    my ($self) = shift;
    my $orig_ref = ref($self);
    bless $self, "#$%^&*()";
    my $fields = $self->{fields};
    bless $self, $orig_ref;
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: hi @mob, this way of accessing the hash indeed works. However, this seems convoluted, with multiple blessings. Will there be a (relatively) huge speed penalty? 
Secondly, can I 'catch' the key that test.pl is looking for when it does $class->{answer}? The key here being 'answer'.

Comment: To capture the key being accessed, you could make `$self->{fields}` into a tied hash (belonging to a separate class than `Record`)

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful and I will try it out. However, as this will be used in loops, the code in `access_hash()` will be executed many times over. How bad is it, in terms of speed, to use the above code? (PS I'm in Perl 5.8.8)

Answer (score 1):

You don't neccessarily need a dedicated constructor for Perl objects. You can define your `Record` class, and then simply `return bless $hashref, 'Record';` where you are now doing `return $hashref;`. All code that operates directly on the hashref will continue to work, but you will also be able to call methods on it.

Comment: @zdim  Fair enough. I rephrased and corrected the error. Thank you for helping me help you help us all.

Comment: Alright. So to help everyone help ourselves, I'll carry on: I still don't understand what you mean -- probably just me not seeing it.  They don't have `return $hashref` -- are you refering to their `access_hash` subroutine (where they return a hashref by name `$self`) ? So do you mean to say that they can just (populate the `$hashref` with data and) bless-and-return right there, without a separate subroutine (`new`) for constructing an object?

Comment: Somewhere in the OPs codebase a hash gets produced and returned and later used. ("wrote a routine that parses a given string and returns a record" / `$record->{data}->{field}`). Put the `bless` into that routine and you're golden.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean -- to make that original package into the class (instead of passing around objects etc). While that may not solve what they're asking it may in fact simplify things overall. It'd be nice to know more about their code to see whether that is possible.  (I still find it unclear in the answer on its own, but it may be just me.)